# Dovecot error - not finding /var/run/dovecot/auth-userdb

Tags: dovecot

I've been trying to set up a Ubuntu postfix/mysql/dovecot mail server and have run into an issue:

from mail.log:

> Error: userdb lookup: connect(/var/run/dovecot/auth-userdb) failed: No
>   such file or directory

I may have mistakenly deleted it, thinking that the system would regenerate it. Is there a way of restoring the file?

Comment: To regenerate the file, restart Dovecot, or just reboot.

Comment: This might also be a permission issue, which should be indicated in the mail log lines near the error message you posted.